# On the sum $I(q^k) + I(n^2)$, where $q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, and denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Let $N = q^k n^2$ be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

It is [known](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(q^k) + I(n^2) < 3.$$

Note that
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(q^k) + \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)}$$
and
$$I(q^k) + I(n^2) = I(n^2) + \dfrac{2}{I(n^2)},$$
so that we have
$$\dfrac{57}{20} < I(n^2) + \dfrac{2}{I(n^2)} < 3.$$

Here is my:

> **QUESTION:** Does this inequality imply that $n^2$ is bounded?

**MY ATTEMPT**

I have
$$n^2 < q^k n^2 = N < 2^{4^{\omega(N)}},$$
where $\omega(N)$ is the *number of distinct prime factors* of $N$.  (Note that the upper bound for $N$ is due to [Nielsen](https://math.byu.edu/%7Epace/upper_bound_web.pdf).)

Hence, $n^2$ is bounded if $\omega(N)$ is bounded.

**Alas, this is where I get stuck.**

Comment: How is $I(n^2) I(q^k) =2$?

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @Tavish.   $I(n^2)I(q^k)=2$ follows from
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2,$$
where $\sigma(m)=2m$ is the *definition* of a number $m$ being *perfect*.  Note that both $\sigma$ and $I$ are multiplicative, and that $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I had mistaken a perfect number to satisfy $\sigma(n)=n$.

Comment: Let $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ be the *aliquot sum* of the positive integer $x$.  Then a number $m$ is *perfect* if $s(m)=m$, @Tavish.

Comment: Anyway, the equation $\sigma(z) = z$ is true *if and only if* $z = 1$.